# Zip two Arrays, always 3 elements of the first array then 2 elements of the second

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I've manually built a method that takes 2 arrays and combines them to 1 like this:

```
a0,a1,a2,b0,b1,a3,a4,a5,b2,b3,a6,...
```

So I always take 3 elements of the first array, then 2 of the second one.
As I said, I built that function manually.

Now I guess I could make this a one-liner instead with the help of `zip`. The problem is, that zip alone is not enough as zip builds tuples like `(a0, b0)`.

Of course I can flatMap this, but still not what I want:

```
val zippedArray: List[Float] = data1.zip(data2).toList.flatMap(t => List(t._1, t._2))
```

That way I'd get a `List(a0, b0, a1, b1,...)`, still not what I want.
(I'd then use toArray for the list... it's more convenient to work with a List right now)

I thought about using `take` and `drop` but they return new data-structures instead of modifying the old one, so not really what I want.

As you can imagine, I'm not really into functional programming (yet). I do use it and I see huge benefits, but some things are so different to what I'm used to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider grouping array `a` by 3, and array `b` by 2, namely

```
val a = Array(1,2,3,4,5,6)
val b = Array(11,22,33,44)

val g = (a.grouped(3) zip b.grouped(2)).toArray
Array((Array(1, 2, 3),Array(11, 22)), (Array(4, 5, 6),Array(33, 44)))
```

Then

```
g.flatMap { case (x,y) => x ++ y }
Array(1, 2, 3, 11, 22, 4, 5, 6, 33, 44)
```

Comment: Learned something new today! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Very similar answer to @elm but I wanted to show that you can use more lazy approach (iterator) to avoid creating temp structures:

```
scala> val a = List(1,2,3,4,5,6)
a: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

scala> val b = List(11,22,33,44)
b: List[Int] = List(11, 22, 33, 44)

scala> val groupped = a.sliding(3, 3) zip b.sliding(2, 2)
groupped: Iterator[(List[Int], List[Int])] = non-empty iterator

scala> val result = groupped.flatMap { case (a, b) => a ::: b }
result: Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator

scala> result.toList
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 11, 22, 4, 5, 6, 33, 44)
```

Note that it stays an iterator all the way until we materialize it with `toList`

Comment: `sliding(n,n)` is the same as `grouped(n)`?

Comment: Yes they are the same, but `sliding` makes an iterator

Comment: So does `grouped`  see http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Array@grouped(size:Int):Iterator[Repr]

Comment: You are right, I guess I misread docs somewhere. Anyway the example is valid. The idea is not to convert to array or list until you need it.